# Intellark keyboard layout for Hebrew language

Tags: keyboard, input-languages

[Intellark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intellark) is an Arabic keyboard layout designed for keyboard typists who is used to type using Latin-based keyboard (i.e. QWERTY based). To exploit the knowledge of the typist, the layout of the keyboard maps arabic and latin letters which have similar phonetic to the same key.

Is there a similar keyboard layout for Hebrew language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. It is called "Hebrew QWERTY". It maps ק to q, ר to r, ת to t and so on.

Naturally this mapping is limited, since Hebrew has sometimes two letters for one phonetic (e.g. ת and ט) and sometimes there are two phonetics associated with one hebrew letter (e.g. פ is used for both the /p/ and /f/ phonetics, and without dagesh the pronounciation of פ is only evident from the context). There are also letters in Hebrew which represent phonetics that have no one-letter equivalent (e.g. צ) or no equivalent at all (ע) in English.

Besides that, Hebrew QWERTY can be quite helpful if one is unaccustomed to Hebrew keyboard layout.